# How to efficiently loop regex searches from set python

Tags: python, regex, loops, dictionary

I'm evaluating a long list of sentences to see if they include state names and map them with a dict, and this is the code I came up with -- it's painfully slow.  How should this be done correctly?

```
       for sent in sentences: #set of sentences.upper()
            for state in stateset: #set of state abbrev's and names in .upper()
                boundst = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % state, re.I)
                if re.search(boundst, sent):
                    sentstatedict[sent] = state
                    break
```

I don't know how to create the bound versions ahead of time - can I create a set of them and use it?

To be clear, I wanted to find out, for each sentence I had, at most one matching state name or abbreviation contained in that sentence.  My difficulty was in not knowing how to pre-assemble a list of usable "bound" versions of the state strings for "whole word" matching.  That led me to having the `re.compile` in the inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're compiling all the regular expressions over and over again (N times! where N is the number of sentences). `re.compile` isn't a speedy operation, so that's what's causing the pain. You can initialize a dict of them so you can look them up by state:

```
re_lookup = {
    state: re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % state, re.I)
    for state in stateset
}

for sent in sentences:
    for state in stateset:
        if re.search(re_lookup[state], sent):
            sentstatedict[sent] = state
            break
```

Comment: `re.compile` caches the patterns you pass to it (whether you call it explicitly, or rely on the implicit compilation of one of the top-level search functions like `re.search` with a string pattern).

Comment: For some reason (call my unpythonic), the dictionaries of dictionaries here make more sense to me than loops in loops in functions.

Comment: This leaves the correct break.  There are only 100 elements in the stateset, so the initial loop doesn't hurt.

Comment: @  Blckknght: Hmmm, how big is the cache? (Probably at least 50 :) )
@ Xodarapp777: Is it less painfully slow now?

Comment: @BrianO: Looking in the source, the cache size is 100 in Python 2 and 512 in recent versions of Python 3. So, the questioner's code probably runs exactly the same speed as yours. Actually, the Questioner's code might be faster if all the sentences have one of the first few states in `stateset` in them. In that specific case, your code does more work (since it compiles all the states, not only the ones that get matched against). Note though that there's a bug suggesting that [explicit calls to `re.compile` shouldn't be cached](https://bugs.python.org/issue17441).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you build a single regex that matches all of your states. Then you can do a single, more complicated regex search against each sentance and extract the matched state from the result:

```
pattern = r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(stateset))
for sent in sentences:
    match = re.search(pattern, sent, re.I)
    if match:
        sentstatedict[sent] = match.group(1)
```

I'm not bothering with `re.compile` because all the regex methods that take string patterns will cache the compiled pattern internally. So searching with the same pattern string should be just as fast as calling `compile` yourself and then using the compiled pattern's methods.

Comment: Plz plz plz modify `if match is not None:` to: `if match:` - it hurts my eyes... :D

Comment: You mean `if match`. The `if not match` was how I originally wrote it and I though that was ugly (proving that tastes may differ), so I changed it to `if match is None` at some point before reversing the logic of the test (when I realized I didn't need to do anything on a failed match). I've changed it again, since I do agree that `if match` is nicer than `if match is not None` (assuming that no other valid value for `match` would be falsey).

Comment: yeah `if match` - told it it hurts my eyes... :)

Comment: This is innovative. But I suspect it won't be faster: the inner loop through states is still there, hidden in the alternation of the big regex. `re.search` will have to perform the loop-until-match-found, by running its state machine simulation (AK? no, ok how about AL? no, ... CA? Yes, break) which introduces some additional overhead. But that's just a hunch. Perhaps OP can benchmark these alternatives?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if it will really be faster or not. It could be, since the actual searching done by the `re` module is implemented in C rather than Python, but it might not be, if there are other overheads.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to compile the regex over and over again (`n^2` times instead of `n` times...). It will be more efficient to change the order of the for-loops and compile the regex in-between:

```
for state in stateset:             
    boundst = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % state, re.I) # compile the regex once (at most) per each state
        for sent in sentences: 
            if re.search(boundst, sent):
                sentstatedict[sent] = state
                break
```

Comment: Yours is slightly better :) but NOT for the reason you state!
You will still compile one regex for each state.

Comment: @BrianO please educate me :) why ?

Comment: Because the outer loop is going to iterate through every state, right?  The break is only breaking to the next sentence iteration.

Comment: Let's say there are N sentences. Mine does 50 `re.compile`s in a separate loop then does the loop body N * 50 times. Yours does just one loop body N * 50 times, and your loop body equals mine plus the `re.compile`. So mine has one more loop setup, AND creates a dict that really is needed (not a big one, but it's still fluff).

Comment: Right, the `break` only breaks the inner loop.

Comment: For some reason, I was thinking that I was breaking the wrong loop if I switched them, but this should return the same number of total matches.  @BrianO, I was timidly answering alfasin asking why his will still compile each state

Comment: @BrianO I stand corrected in regards to `break` but it was a simple fix :)  [wrapping it in a function and returning]

Comment: Also, note that our two versions don't have the same semantics. If sentence `sent` contain more than one state name, `sentstatedict[sent]` will be (or can be) different in your version. My version preserves OP's semantics, and to do that,  I had to create the dict :)
So unfortunately I have to recant: for that reason, I think mine is a slightly better answer, but yours is a little more efficient (both time & space).

Comment: `return` is surely wrong. You'll only ever add at most one value to `sentstatedict`, rather than (up to) one per sentence.

Comment: Assuming the OP wants to bail out on the first match - a `return` is what is needed. Else, I need to better understand what the OP wants to achieve in order to decide if a `break` should be placed there or not.

Comment: Oh no, no: now your answer is simply wrong, it's not a correct answer anymore.
It's only going set  `sentstatedict[sent] = state` **for the first sentence* `sent` that contains a state, *and then it returns*. *This means something completely different.*

OP, are you listening? :)

Comment: @BrianO and Blckkngt  -since the OP didn't define properly which result exactly does he want to achieve upon match - all guesses are equally right (or wrong). Returning on the first match is good if that's what he's looking for, otherwise, depending on the requirements, `break` (or nothing at all) will be the right thing to do.

Comment: BTW, that's the reason I ended the reasoning with "if you run into a "match" on the first iteration - you've compiled only **one** regex!"

Comment: @ alfasin: I have to disagree. If he wanted only one match, then why in heck have the dict `sentstatedict` at all??? Just one item, a single tuple (sent, state), would suffice.

Comment: @BrianO you're right, reverting to the previous version! probably time I go to bed...

Comment: I now understand the original reasoning and edited my original question.  This is my fault, but what I have is actually a CSV of PPC key phrases, so I'm stuck iterating rows, for each of which, there is a sentence - so they aren't actually in a set.  Since that iteration is the outer loop, I can't run the states one loop out.  This is why I was stuck with the `re.compile` on the inner loop.

Comment: @BrianO btw - not sure I understand your comment about "keeping the semantics": changing the order of the loops will not damage the results - only the order they were inserted. But maybe I'm too tired, will have another look at it tomorrow when I'm fresh.

Comment: @Xodarap777 not sure I understand the reason you can't change the order, but assuming you're right and there's no other way - I would recommend using the solution BrianO provided!